# Unmarshall errorExpected elements are <{}>

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am getting a strange error during unmarshalling.

This is my unmarshal code

```
File file = new File("resources/test.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FuzzyControllerType.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
FuzzyControllerType fct=(FuzzyControllerType) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

This is the error I get:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element 
(uri:"", local:"FuzzyController"). Expected elements are <{}fuzzyControllerType>
```

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FuzzyController>
    <KnowledgeBase>
    <FuzzyVariable name="food" domainleft="0.0" domainright="10.0" scale="" type="input">        
            <FuzzyTerm name="delicious" complement="false">
                <LeftLinearShape Param1="5.5" Param2="10.0"/>
            </FuzzyTerm>
            <FuzzyTerm name="rancid" complement="false">
                <TriangularShape Param1="0.0" Param2="2.0" Param3="5.5"/>
            </FuzzyTerm>
        </FuzzyVariable>
   </KnowledgeBase>
</FuzzyController>
```

My Fuzzy controller type class looks like this:

```
package testfuzzy;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "FuzzyControllerType", propOrder = {
    "knowledgeBase"
})
@XmlRootElement(name="FuzzyControllerType")
public class FuzzyControllerType {

    @XmlElement(name = "KnowledgeBase", required = true)
    protected KnowledgeBaseType knowledgeBase;
    public KnowledgeBaseType getKnowledgeBase() {
        return knowledgeBase;
    }
    public void setKnowledgeBase(KnowledgeBaseType value) {
        this.knowledgeBase = value;
    }

}
```

I haven't used any name spaces. How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you think is `@XmlRootElement.name` stand for?

Comment: I didnt understand your question?

Comment: you're trying to unmarshall object considering root element name is `FuzzyControllerType`, as defined in `@XmlRootElement.name`, but actually it is `FuzzyController`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your XML document has the root element **"FuzzyController"**

Add the annotation `@XmlRootElement(name="FuzzyController")` to the class.

Hope it will help you.

**UPDATE:**

Change your code like this

```
package testfuzzy;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "FuzzyController", propOrder = {
    "knowledgeBase"
})
@XmlRootElement(name="FuzzyController")
public class FuzzyController {

    @XmlElement(name = "KnowledgeBase", required = true)
    protected KnowledgeBaseType knowledgeBase;
    public KnowledgeBaseType getKnowledgeBase() {
        return knowledgeBase;
    }
    public void setKnowledgeBase(KnowledgeBaseType value) {
        this.knowledgeBase = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd leave `@XmlType.name` as it is (`FuzzyControllerType`) as it can define some existing type.

Comment: did this. This is my output:

testfuzzy.FuzzyController@3b0def13

Comment: You are getting the object. you need to get value from the object